# How to add a New Action to the mobile App

Tags: acumatica

Good day

Build 20.107.0026

I have created a New Action and want to add it to my Mobile app. Is it possible to add a custom action to a mobile screen? I have created the below action in the Appointment screen(FS300200)

```
namespace PX.Objects.FS
{
    // Acuminator disable once PX1016 ExtensionDoesNotDeclareIsActiveMethod extension should be constantly active
    public class AppointmentEntry_Extension : PXGraphExtension<AppointmentEntry>
  {
    #region Event Handlers

    public PXAction<PX.Objects.FS.FSAppointment> DoWork;
  
    [PXButton(CommitChanges = true)]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "DoWork")]
    protected void doWork()
    {

    }

    #endregion
  }
}
```

Mobile code below. If I want to add the button to the main menu; the 3 dots on the side do I use AppointmentRecords as the container?

```
update screen FS300200 {
  update container "AppointmentRecords" {
     add listAction "StartTravelAPICall" {
        behavior = Void
        displayName = "StartTravelAPICall"
      }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is YES!  The long answer depends in part on what version of Acumatica you are using.  For the purpose of this answer, I'll assume you are in 2019R2 and already know how to add or edit a Mobile App screen in Acumatica.  If not, the training guides referenced below should give you all the detailed information you need to accomplish your goal.

Manipulating the Mobile App screens/actions is relatively easy if the screen/action works in the browser interface.  The [T410](https://openuni.acumatica.com/courses/development/t410-customization-of-mobile-application-advanced/) course material explains how to add an action in 2019R2.  I don't work with Field Services, so I'll have to explain more generically as per the training guide.

First you must either add or edit the screen in the Mobile Application section of the Customization Project.  (In your case, you want to Update the existing screen.)  This will create a section of code in the customization project that looks like this:
[image]

As you can see, the original screen definition in the mobile app is shown on the right, and you will be updating the screen to add your action.  You will need to add the appropriate container (not shown in your question) and then the action within that container.

To continue the answer, let's switch to the training guide example on page 12 of the T410 course updating the SO303000 screen.  You can compare to your screen to see what needs to be changed.

```
add container "InvoiceSummary" {
  # fields declaration
  …
  add recordAction "Save" {
    behavior = Save
  }
  add recordAction "Cancel" {
    behavior = Cancel
  }
  add containerAction "Insert" {
    behavior = Create
  }
  add recordAction "ReleaseAction" {
    syncLongOperation = true
    behavior = Record
  }
}
```

I believe your action would follow the ReleaseAction portion at the bottom of the example, and the need for syngLongOperation = true would depend on what your action is doing (i.e. if you need the action performed asynchronously).

Assuming your container is already defined in the page, which I suspect it is, let's instead look at the example for PO302000 on page 35. This example shows how to UPDATE a container to add your action.

```
update screen PO302000 {
  update container "DocumentSummary" {
    add recordAction "AddPOOrderLine" {
      displayName = "Add PO Line"
      behavior = Void
      redirect = True
      redirectToContainer = "AddPurchaseOrderLine$List"
    }
  }
}
```

That was a more complex action, but yours may be as simple as.

```
update screen FS300200 {
  update container "ServiceOrderTypeLine" {
    add listAction "DoWork" {
      Behavior = Void
      displayName = "Do Work"
    }
  }
}
```

If you need guidance on how to read the WDSL Schema to identify the container, etc. that training is found in [T400](https://openuni.acumatica.com/courses/development/t400-customization-of-mobile-application-basic/) starting on Page 13.

I highly recommend reviewing both [T400](https://openuni.acumatica.com/courses/development/t400-customization-of-mobile-application-basic/) and [T410](https://openuni.acumatica.com/courses/development/t410-customization-of-mobile-application-advanced/) if you are working with the mobile app as there is a lot more detail in those training guides than can be explained easily in a Stack Overflow post/answer.

Comment: Hi Brian thanks for the thought explanation. I updated my question. I added that I am building in  20.107.0026. Also added the functions name I am calling. it is an API that I need to do that saves data, will that change the behavior I pick?